# Transposing dataframe column, creating different rows per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` that has one column and a timestamp index including anywhere from 2 to 7 days:

```
                         kWh
Timestamp                   
2017-07-08 06:00:00     0.00
2017-07-08 07:00:00   752.75
2017-07-08 08:00:00  1390.20
2017-07-08 09:00:00  2027.65
2017-07-08 10:00:00  2447.27    
        ....           ....
2017-07-12 20:00:00   167.64
2017-07-12 21:00:00     0.00
2017-07-12 22:00:00     0.00
2017-07-12 23:00:00     0.00
```

I would like to transpose the `kWh` column so that one day's worth of values (hourly granularity, so 24 values/day) fill up a row.  And the next row is the next day of values and so on (so five days of forecasted data has five rows with 24 elements each).

Because my query of the data comes in the vertical format, and my regression and subsequent analysis already occurs in the vertical format, I don't want to change the process too much and am hoping there is a simpler way.  I have tried giving a multi-index with `df.index.hour` and then using `unstack()`, but I get a huge `dataframe` with `NaN` values everywhere.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you show your `MultiIndex` code - don't see why that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start from a frame like

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({"kWh": [1]}, index=pd.date_range("2017-07-08", 
             "2017-07-12", freq="1H").rename("Timestamp")).cumsum()

In [26]: df.head()
Out[26]: 
                     kWh
Timestamp               
2017-07-08 00:00:00    1
2017-07-08 01:00:00    2
2017-07-08 02:00:00    3
2017-07-08 03:00:00    4
2017-07-08 04:00:00    5
```

we can make date and hour columns and then pivot:

```
In [27]: df["date"] = df.index.date

In [28]: df["hour"] = df.index.hour

In [29]: df.pivot(index="date", columns="hour", values="kWh")
Out[29]: 
hour          0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...   \
date                                                                    ...    
2017-07-08   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  ...    
2017-07-09  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  ...    
2017-07-10  49.0  50.0  51.0  52.0  53.0  54.0  55.0  56.0  57.0  58.0  ...    
2017-07-11  73.0  74.0  75.0  76.0  77.0  78.0  79.0  80.0  81.0  82.0  ...    
2017-07-12  97.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    

hour          14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23  
date                                                                    
2017-07-08  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  
2017-07-09  39.0  40.0  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0  47.0  48.0  
2017-07-10  63.0  64.0  65.0  66.0  67.0  68.0  69.0  70.0  71.0  72.0  
2017-07-11  87.0  88.0  89.0  90.0  91.0  92.0  93.0  94.0  95.0  96.0  
2017-07-12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your `MultiIndex` code doesn't work. 
I'm assuming your `MultiIndex` code is something along the lines, which gives the same output as the `pivot`:

```
In []
df = pd.DataFrame({"kWh": [1]}, index=pd.date_range("2017-07-08", 
                   "2017-07-12", freq="1H").rename("Timestamp")).cumsum()
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.date, df.index.hour], names=['Date','Hour'])
df.unstack()

Out[]:
             kWh                                                        ...   \
Hour          0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...    
Date                                                                    ...    
2017-07-08   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  ...    
2017-07-09  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  ...    
2017-07-10  49.0  50.0  51.0  52.0  53.0  54.0  55.0  56.0  57.0  58.0  ...    
2017-07-11  73.0  74.0  75.0  76.0  77.0  78.0  79.0  80.0  81.0  82.0  ...    
2017-07-12  97.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    


Hour          14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23  
Date                                                                    
2017-07-08  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  
2017-07-09  39.0  40.0  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0  47.0  48.0  
2017-07-10  63.0  64.0  65.0  66.0  67.0  68.0  69.0  70.0  71.0  72.0  
2017-07-11  87.0  88.0  89.0  90.0  91.0  92.0  93.0  94.0  95.0  96.0  
2017-07-12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```

​